# Debugging in VS2013 with WCF

Tags: c#, winforms, wcf, visual-studio-2013

Due to recent hardware failure, I've had to go back to an old laptop of mine.  I newly installed VS2013 on Win8 and am finding a new behavior.  Used to be, when I would debug one of my Winforms projects, the other included WCF application projects would automatically launch to the

```
http://localhost:42898
```

(etc) address.  Now, with this new install of VS2013, I can't get the IIS Express versions to launch when I'm debugging my other projects.

Does anyone know of how to configure VS to automatically build and launch these ancillary web apps during debugging of winform apps?

Comment: You should check your solution's startup projects. You can have more than one. That might not be enough, but it's worth a shot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for multiple startup projects. Right click on your solution and select Properties -> Startup Project -> Multiple Startup Projects:

[image]

Now when you hit <kbd>F5</kbd> both your WCF service and WinForms applications will start in Debug mode.